# Jasper Report -- Hashmap or Sub report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

The back end of Java application can return a series of tables, every table is with the same structure, just like search for "information of schools which in specific area" can return dynamic amount of schools with its information, now we want to make each school detail as a table.

```
-School A-
=============================
Name | Address | Student Name

-School B-
=============================
Name | Address | Student Name

....

-School N-
=============================
Name | Address | Student Name
```

Then can we use HashMap in Jasper to save the trouble of sub report and still keep everything dynamic ? Any hint is grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you return all the data in one table (you say that thet tables you now get have the same structure)?

If not directly from a database then write your own data source class that would wrap all the tables into one data source for Jasper.

Then put the data to the detail of the report and tell Jasper to do grouping on School column.

Comment: Thank you. I can pack everything in one datasource table but how can Jasper solve it into separate tables? It's all about better layout to fulfill the requirement otherwise we can put the School Title as the first column and sort the result set "ORDER BY" its title so that everything is in one table, but still that is only one table, can we put the title as header row of each different table?

Comment: Just tell Jasper to group on the scholl column and everything will be ok.

Comment: Is it something like "ColSpan" in HTML?

Comment: Nope, it's like GROUP BY in SQL language

Comment: sorry, I mean RowSpan in HTML. So each school title cell is merged in to one big cell, just like GROUP BY ?

Comment: I'm not an HTML guy, so I'll give you an example.
Let's say you have a table with this data:
A     1
B     2
A     3
B     4
then a GROUP BY on the first column would result in this data:
A     1
A     3
B     2
B     4
and Jasper knows how to draw this nicely.
More on JAsper grouping http://ireport.sourceforge.net/cap5.html and "Jasper Sample" on http://fecplanner.com/jasperreports/docs/samples/index.html